# floating elements swapped

Tags: css, floating

I have wordpress page http://war-mobile.h2client.com/corporate-information/our-team/ and am developing a mobile website for it. If you go to the bottom and click on `switch to our mobile` you will see that the image and the info div have swapped places - I copied the style from the original site as far as the image and the floating div go, but am having this problem. Code:

```
.bios div {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: 35px;
float: left;
display: block;
}


.bios avatar {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 130px;
height: 165px;
margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a simplyfied example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: MY MISTAKE - was missing a dot - .avatar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be `.bios .avatar` (notice the additional period) or `.bios img` as in the non-mobile version.  Either sets the float for the img properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.bios img {float: left;}
```

the avatar selector does not select the image in the mobile version

edit:

Infact, the CSS for the avatar class misses a dot

```
.bios .avatar {...}
```

thus it is not applied to any element.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to add this property:

```
.bios img{
   float:left;
}
```

But I'm afraid that your divs are way too mixed up.. You will need to clean them up to fix the more button as well..